# ASP.NET Button press does not update object

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

```
List<Button> buttons { get; set; }
Queue<string> myQueue { get; set; }


public void AssignButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    OutputMessage.Text = "Clicked button: " + btn.Text;
    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    btn.Text = myQueue.Dequeue();
}


//initialize buttons
foreach (Button b in Buttons_)
{
    if (b.Text.Equals("wait"))
    {
        if (myQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            b.Text = myQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
           break;
        }
    }
}


myQueue = new Queue<string>();
myQueue.Enqueue("1");
myQueue.Enqueue("2");
...
myQueue.Enqueue("13");


Buttons_ = new List<Button>();
Buttons_.Add(Button1);
...
Buttons_.Add(Button9);
```

I have buttons that will be update after each click. They will be filled with a number. Think of it as a counting game for children, where the queue starts at 1 and goes to 100. I can initialize the buttons correctly and can access the data, but the object is not update, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myQueue is your class member, everytime you do button click postback occurs and new instance of page is created. So if You want to preserve this queue you can do this in multiple ways by using any of these variables depending on your requirement.

1. ViewState
2. Session
3. Cookies

Comment: Thanks! All I needed were those ideas to know where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using asp.net, the state of your queue is not saved across the responses. In other words, a new queue is being created for each button press, so when you `Dequeue`, it returns `"1"` since that is the first string in the queue. If you just need to update the number, you could do this:

```
int value;
if(int.TryParse(btn.Text, out value))
{
    btn.Text = (value + 1).ToString();
}
```

This is assuming that your button starts with an integer value as the text